# MouseUp / Click on Image does not work unless it has a Source

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 15 images.. where I have "On Mouse Up", have it open up a windows explorer browser window so they can choose what image to put as the source.

the thing is if there is nothing in the image source originally.. mouse up doesn't work...

is there any way around this?

```
private void Image_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Configure open file dialog box 
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name 
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".png"; // Default file extension 
            dlg.Filter = "PNG Files (.png)|*.png|TGA Files (.tga)|*.tga|All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // Filter files by extension 

            // Show open file dialog box 
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Process open file dialog box results 
            if (result == true)
            {
                ((Image)sender).Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Edit for Vimal CK:

```
<GroupBox Width="75" Height="75">
                            <Border MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseUp1">
                                <Image Name="RedPick5_Image" Height="45" Width="45"></Image>
                            </Border>
                        </GroupBox>

private void Image_MouseUp1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("in here");
            // Configure open file dialog box 
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name 
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".png"; // Default file extension 
            dlg.Filter = "PNG Files (.png)|*.png|TGA Files (.tga)|*.tga|All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // Filter files by extension 

            // Show open file dialog box 
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

            // Process open file dialog box results 
            if (result == true)
            {
                RedPick5_Image.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(dlg.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the snippet what you tried?

Comment: sure, will edit in a second

Comment: so this works if i put an image source to it (set an image).  otherwise this doesn't work.. just trying to find a work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `default Background for Border is null` which `does not respond to HitTest` i.e. won't respond to MouseEvents. All you need is to `set Background to Transparent` for your border which will enable it for hit test scenarios.

```
<GroupBox Width="75" Height="75">
   <Border MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseUp1" Background="Transparent">
       <Image Name="RedPick5_Image" Height="45" Width="45"></Image>
   </Border>
</GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround to this. It is by design. An Image without Source is more or less equal to null and so hit testing (clicking with mouse around) is not available. As soon you set the Source the Image will have the capability to participate in hit testing.

If you would take a control and set its background color to null you would notice that clicking is not being handled.

Comment: You could apply an empty source to Image or wrap the Image with a Border. Or something like that... Be creative :)

Comment: tried the border thing as suggested by Vimal CK below to no avail =\  still trying to think of workarounds...

Comment: Another workaround would be to add BitmapSource.Create to source and instead create you simply create a transparent image :)

Comment: i'm desperate for anything here.. otherwise i have to change alot of code.  so tired, promise to come back in the morning at work and try this. gawd i hope this works =[

Comment: Since you set source in code you will be able to call BitmapSource.Create method

Comment: do you think you can post an example of this?

Comment: nevermind i found some examples onlnie that use bitmapsource.create, thanks will try it out tmrw

Answer (score 1):

I have a work around on this issue. Modify your XAML by adding a border control like below. Since the `MouseLeftButtonUp` is an attached event. So you can hook this event to any `FrameworkElement` like below.

```
<Border MouseLeftButtonUp="Image1_MouseUp">
   <Image Name="Image1"
          Width="200"
          Height="200">
   </Image>
</Border>
```

Your code required a slight change as follows

```
private void Image1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = ""; // Default file name 
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".png"; // Default file extension 
        dlg.Filter = "PNG Files (.png)|*.png|TGA Files (.tga)|*.tga|All Files (*.*)|*.*"; // Filter files by extension 

        // Show open file dialog box 
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        // Process open file dialog box results 
        if (result == true)
        {
            Image1.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString(dlg.FileName);
        }

    }
```

instead of using `((Image)sender).Source`, assign the image directly to `Image` control. Please check if it feasible for you.

Comment: will try this out and come back and let you know if it works!  tyvm

Comment: i did up-arrow it -.-

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately... bleh  i can't get the (new) imageup method to fire..

Comment: Please share your XAML snippet

Comment: edited OP for you.  even if i remove the groupbox around it, it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the GroupBox really required? Because it holds only one image control.

Comment: it's part of the GUI design.  i tried messing with the border and all it's mouse properties.. regardless of the groupbox or not.. the border mouse events will only fire if there's an image in the source still unfortunately